# Connecting dots with an ordered list in CSS3

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm just trying to connect some dots with an ordered list but I cannot make  it work. I want to turn on a segment according to the active class and additionally I want to add the name of the student between the segment like this picture[image]

Then I can switch to turn on the other segment with the class active.

This is what I've been trying to do.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muvmcam6/2/)

**UPDATE**

I updated my fiddle because I forgot to add the class active to the li element

**UPDATE**

I updated again my fiddle to show where I should go the name of the person.

```css
ol.timetable li {
    min-width: 25%;
}

.timetable {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    .timetable li {
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    .timetable .date {
        display: block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        color: #2B2B2B;
    }

    .timetable .dot {
        color: black;
        border: 3px solid #B2B2B2;
        background-color: #B2B2B2;
        border-radius: 50%;
        line-height: 1.2;
        width: 1.2em;
        height: 1.2em;
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .timetable .active .date,
    .timetable .active .dot span {
        color: black;
    }

    .timetable .dot:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: #B2B2B2;
        height: 0.4em;
        width: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0.9em;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .timetable .dot:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: #B2B2B2;
        height: 0.4em;
        width: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0.9em;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .timetable li:first-child .dot:before {
        display: none;
    }

        .timetable li:first-child .dot:after .active {
            border: 3px solid #F26227 !important;
            background-color: #F26227 !important;
        }

    .timetable li:last-of-type .dot:after {
        display: none;
    }

     .timetable .active .dot {
        border: 3px solid #F26227;
        background-color: #F26227;
    }

    .timetable .active .dot:before,
    .timetable .active .dot:before {
        background-color: #F26227;
    }
```

```html
<ol class='timetable'>
<li class="active">
  <span class='date'>5/26/2017</span>
  <span class='active dot'>
     <span>
     </span>
  </span>
</li>
<li class="active">
   <span class='date'>5/29/2017</span>
   <span class='active dot'>
      <span></span>
   </span>
</li>
<li>
   <span class='date'>6/5/2017</span>
   <span class='dot'>
      <span></span>
   </span>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Where in your HTML are you planning on putting the name of the student? Can you update your code so it (at least attempts to) address the name display part of the problem?

Comment: To further press for details, is there supposed to be a label under every segment, or just the latest? If all three dots are active, where should the label be?

Comment: I updated my question. A label under each segment. But the label is gonna be added in the accurate segment dynamically. So in one segment it should appear on the left in other cases on the right. The thing is the alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify how much CSS you need to write, I'd suggest making each line segment composed of just one long `:before` pseudo-element, rather than a combination of a `:before` and `:after`. This also makes it simpler to fill in the preceding line segment when the associated item is active.

For placement of the label, I'm going to assume you'll be adding/removing the `<span>` containing it dynamically, so it'll be up to you to determine where it should be best placed. To position and center it accordingly, I suggest absolute positioning and a small transformation to center the text.

Putting this all together, you get:

```css
ol.timetable li {
  min-width: 25%;
}
.timetable {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.timetable li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.timetable .date {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  color: #2B2B2B;
}
.timetable .dot {
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid #B2B2B2;
  background-color: #B2B2B2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
}
.timetable .active .date,
.timetable .active .dot span {
  color: black;
}
.timetable .dot:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #B2B2B2;
  height: 0.4em;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.9em;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.timetable li:first-child .dot:before {
  display: none;
}
.timetable .active .dot {
  border: 3px solid #F26227;
  background-color: #F26227;
}
.timetable .active + .active .dot:before {
  background-color: #F26227;
}
.timetable li > span:nth-child(3){
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:-15px;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<ol class='timetable'>
  <li class="active">
    <span class='date'>5/26/2017</span>
    <span class='active dot'>
     <span>
     </span>
    </span>
    <span>John Doe</span>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <span class='date'>5/29/2017</span>
    <span class='active dot'>
      <span></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class='date'>6/5/2017</span>
    <span class='dot'>
      <span></span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Note that if the label element isn't guaranteed to be in the same place within the item, I'd suggest adding a class to it to make it easier to target with CSS. Also, if you'd like to hide any unfilled lines behind the active dots, just set the `z-index` on `.timetable .dot:before` to a negative value.

Also note the usage of the sibling selector in `.timetable .active + .active .dot:before`. This ensures that only the line between two active dots will be highlighted, rather than every line associated with an active item.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I just works for the first segment but I got a problem when I switch to the other segment. It means that the middle and the last dots will have the class = active.

Comment: @MaximusDecimus I see - do you mean that only up to two dots can be `.active` at any given time?

Comment: @MaximusDecimus Alright, I've made a tweak to a selector that should address that need.